# Error al ingresar la URL en minuscula Angular 4,6,7

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema al momento de ingresar o pegar la url en minuscula de mi aplicacion.

Si escribo o pego la url de esta forma:

```
http://localhost:4200/Clientes/Naturales
```

Funciona correctamente

pero si la ingreso o la pego de esta forma

```
http://localhost:4200/clientes/naturales
```

Me saca error como si la ulr no existiera

Estoy direccionando con router en angular 7, puedo hacer algo para que no importa como venga la url me funcione el ingreso ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existen dos opciones:

1) La más sencilla pero posiblemente algo tediosa para muchas rutas es definir rutas para redirigir el tráfico:

```
{ path: '/clientes', redirectTo: ['/Clientes'] },
{ path: '/Clientes', component: ClientesComponent, name: 'Clientes' },
```

2) Algo que considero una mejor solución es crear una clase que serialize las urls y las convierta a lowerCase, upperCase o lo que necesites:

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export class LowerCaseUrlSerializer extends DefaultUrlSerializer {
    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
        return super.parse(url.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

y utilizarla en tu app

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: UrlSerializer,
            useClass: LowerCaseUrlSerializer
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Sólo tienes que agregarlo para los providers en el module principal. No lo agregues en todos.

Comment: Lo agrege al app pero al ingresar me manda a la pagina de error , ahora convierte la url siempre a minuscula, la idea es que si la ingresa en minuscula me deje ingresar no que la modifique, las url en el routing están declaradas con camelcase

Comment: Sí, de hecho **url.toLowerCase()** siempre convertirá todo a minúscula ... pero dentro del parse puedes escribir las reglas que necesites para tu aplicación trabajando con el parámetro **url** que le estás pasando a la función.